# How can Ant Colony Optimization be made to produce more consistent results?

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics, mathematical-optimization, ant-colony

I developed a software implementation of Ant Colony Optimization to solve the Traveling Salesman Problem, but due to ACO's stochastic nature, each execution of the ACO algorithm produces a different near optimal solution every time. Is there a way to make ACO more deterministic? I understand that it will never be 100% deterministic but I need it to be able to run multiple times on the same problem space and at least come up with a similar solution most of the time. I've tried tweaking α, β, ρ and number of iterations but I'm just shooting in the dark at this point.

Comment: Are you using a PRNG to place the ants at random cities initially (and perhaps to do random moves for some ants)? If so, you could try seeding the PRNG with the same value for every run.

Comment: Ants always start in the same cities but the pseudo-random-proportional action choice rule introduces randomness.  Even so, I'm reading that it is theoretically possible for the ants to converge on the global best solution. I'm just not sure how to do it.

Comment: Is this a plain ACO implementation, or some variant? Do all ants contribute pheromone, or only the ones that generated the shortest tours during the previous iteration (or a psuedo-random selection of ants)? What function are you using for calculating the probability of an ant moving from its current location to a given city?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Michael already stated as a comment: **use a seeded pseudo random number generator (PRNG) and reuse the same all over your implementation**.

In Java, do something like this:

```
Random workingRandom = new Random(0L);
// Never use Math.random(), always use workingRandom.next*() instead
```

There are a couple of other things you might need to disable (especially in multi-threaded implementations) to have 100% reproducibility, some of which I discuss in my implementation's docs section [4.4.3.4. REPRODUCIBLE](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#environmentMode) (such as replacing `HashMap` by `LinkedHashMap` when needed).